# Create new variable showing whether values in variable x is larger than values in variables y and z: handling ties.

Tags: r, if-statement

I have three variables and want to create a new variable indicating if the first variable (x) is largest (=1) or not (=0). If there is a tie between two variables this should be indicated as 0.5; and if there are a tie between all three variables this should be indicated with 0.33. 
Here are example data

```
 x= c(5, 1, 5, 5, 4)
 y= c(1, 1, 5, 5, 5)
 z= c(1, 2, 4, 5, 5)
 data <-data.frame(x, y, z)
```

This is how it should be in the end

```
 correct = c(1, 0, 0.5, 0.333, 0)
 datafinal <- data.frame(x, y, z, correct)
 datafinal

> datafinal
   x y z correct
 1 5 1 1   1.000
 2 1 1 2   0.000
 3 5 5 4   0.500
 4 5 5 5   0.333
 5 4 5 5   0.000
```

I have started with the below; however, when it is a tie it appears to randomly assign a number which makes me think I am on the wrong path?

```
  data$correct <- ifelse(max.col(data)==1, 1, 0)
```

Very grateful for any help. 
Gorp

Comment: Your conjecture about `max.col` is correct. Look at its documentation with `?max.col`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
is_max       <- sweep(data, 1, apply(data,1,max), "==")

data$correct <- is_max[,"x"]/rowSums(is_max)
```

I think of this as computing the share of the winnings that `x` gets for having the highest score. The numerator is whether `x` won; and the denominator, the number of winners.

(I can't think of any story that would justify calling this var `correct`, though...)

Comment: A single apply can also work `apply(data,1,function(x) {p<-x==max(x);p[1]/sum(p)})`

Comment: @A.Webb That's true. I don't really have a sense for what's best: a sequence of computations for each row (like yours); or a sequence of matrix computations making an intermediate object (like mine). The latter might be nice if they are going to do the same thing for "y" and "z", but I haven't really thought about it.